# how do I handle an optional trailing comma?

Tags: f#, fparsec

given the following

```
let maxCount = System.Int32.MaxValue
let pmlcomment = pstring "/*" >>. skipCharsTillString "*/" true (maxCount)
let ws = pspaces >>. many (pspaces >>. pmlcomment .>> pspaces) |>> (function | [] -> () | _ -> ())
let str_ws s = pstring s .>> ws
let exprBraceSeqOpt p =
    let trailingComma = (str_ws "," |>> fun _ -> None )
    between (str_ws "{") (str_ws "}") ((opt (attempt (sepBy p (str_ws ",")))) <|> (attempt trailingComma))
let sampleP = exprBraceSeqOpt (str_ws "x")
```

it properly matches all of the following except the last one:

```
["{}";"{x}";"{x,x}";"{x,x,}"]
```

I'm guessing something is altering the state or something.

How do I handle an optional trailing comma in fparsec?

Comment: Perhaps it should be `opt (attempt trailingComma)`?

Comment: nope, that doesn't compile

Answer (score 4):

`sepBy` "eats up" the extra separator if it is present. That's just how it works, period. You cannot hack it by applying `attempt` in various places: if you apply `attempt` to the separator, it won't help, because the last separator actually succeeds, so `attempt` will have no effect. And applying `attempt` to the whole `sepBy` will also not help, because then the whole `sepBy` will be rolled back, not just the last separator. And applying `attempt` to the "x" parser itself, while achieving the desired trailing comma behavior, would also have the adverse effect of making the parser accept multiple commas in a row.

And because it is impossible to achieve the desired result via clever use of combinators, there is actually a special function for doing just what you're after - `sepEndBy`.

This would work as desired:

```
let exprBraceSeqOpt p =
    between (str_ws "{") (str_ws "}") (sepEndBy p (str_ws ","))
```

Also, as an aside, I should point out that `function | [] -> () | _ -> ()` is a remarkably elaborate way to do `ignore`. :-)

Comment: very nice information. as for the ignore... I trimmed this down poorly for general consumption, there are things in there in my actual code =)